# Curl command not working on linux machine via mac terminal

Tags: linux, macos, curl, installation, virtual-machine

I am trying to install chef on my linux based Virtual Machine.
I am connecting to VM via my mac terminal and login to the vm.
Turns out when I am running curl command from my mac terminal, it doesn’t work. But the same works from window machine using putty.
is there any restriction from running curl on a VM from mac terminal and not from windows putty?

curl -L https://www.chef.io/chef/install.sh | bash -s -- -v 12.4.2-1

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: Connection timed out.
got resolved after export command for http_proxy
Thanks